# ¿Saber como se realiza esta acción con jquery en html javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy realizando un examen con un compañero y queremos realizar este efecto con los iconos de redes sociales, pero no encontramos el como realizarlo, por si alguien sabe como realizar se lo agradezco.

Es el efecto para mostrar información adicional en la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que cuando pones el cursor sobre el logo de youtube te salga lo de **"Pagina de inicio de Youtube"** ?

Comment: vale gracias por la ayuda, aunque sea algo basico me sirve ;)

Comment: Si puedes acepta una respuesta para que esta pregunta se marque como respondida

Answer (score 2):

Eso no necesita JQuery. Al menos en su versión básica. Ese el atributo `title` de la etiqueta `<a>`.

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Está representado como

```
<a href="https://stackexchange.com/users/84585?tab=reputation" ... title="Logros recientes: reputación, medallas y privilegios obtenidos" role="menuitem" ...>
   ...
</a>
```

Si examinas la página que muestras como ejemplo, funciona igual.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar el atributo title, todos los elementos HTML los tienes por ejemplo

```
<img src="any.png" title="Esto es una imagen"></img>
```

Lo que mostrará la información en un tooltip